# Does Orca screen reader have a Caption Panel?

Tags: accessibility, orca

**VoiceOver**, the screen reader of MacOS, has a *Caption Panel*, this feature shows visually the text that the screen reader is announcing.
[image: Caption Panel from VoiceOver MacOS]

This is very handy for developers working to enable content for screen reader users.

Does **Orca**, default [Ubuntu's screen reader](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-screen-reader.html.en) have a *Caption Panel*?

Comment: What does your question have to do with the Ubuntu OS?

Comment: @David Orca is the [default screen reader](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-screen-reader.html.en) of Ubuntu OS

Comment: did you ever figure out? I was looking for captions like VO as well in Ocra

Comment: @Danish as far as I know, this feature is not part of Orca

Comment: lame @nulll ubuntu have such a bad support for screen readers